# How to serialize and deserialize a PFX certificate in Azure Key Vault?

Tags: c#, azure, certificate, x509certificate2, azure-keyvault

I have a bunch of strings and pfx certificates, which I want to store in Azure Key vault, where only allowed users/apps will be able to get them. It is not hard to do store a string as a Secret, but how can I serialize a certificate in such way that I could retrieve it and deserialize as an **[X509Certificate2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx)** object in C#?

I tried to store it as a key. Here is the Azure powershell code

```
$securepfxpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'superSecurePassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$key = Add-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName 'UltraVault' -Name 'MyCertificate' -KeyFilePath 'D:\Certificates\BlaBla.pfx' -KeyFilePassword $securepfxpwd
```

But when I tried to get it with **[GetKeyAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt134031.aspx)** method, I couldn't use it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a PowerShell script for you. Replace the file path, password, vault name, secret name.

```
$pfxFilePath = 'C:\mycert.pfx'
$pwd = '123'
$flag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable
$collection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection 
$collection.Import($pfxFilePath, $pwd, $flag)
$pkcs12ContentType = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12
$clearBytes = $collection.Export($pkcs12ContentType)
$fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($clearBytes)
$secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $fileContentEncoded -AsPlainText –Force
$secretContentType = 'application/x-pkcs12'
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'myVaultName' -Name 'mySecretName' -SecretValue $Secret -ContentType $secretContentType
```

This is a common question, so we are going to polish this up and release as a helper.

The script above strips the password because there's no value in having a password protected PFX and then storing the password next to it.

Comment: The $clearBytes = $collection.Export($pkcs12ContentType) doesn't appear to export the private key. Using the $collection.Export($pkcs12ContentType, $pwd) method allowed me to import the certificate as a X509Certificate2 (c#) using the password.

Comment: @Sumedh The helper you are referring to is that the new Key Vault certificates feature? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/certificate-scenarios Thank you

Comment: @HBoyce yes indeed. Here is a tutorial for the certificates feature. Much more concise now than the script above, and your certificates stay auto-renewed too. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2016/09/26/get-started-with-azure-key-vault-certificates/

(Thank you for resurrecting this thread.)

Comment: Ok, so it comes back as a 'Secret' and not as a 'Certification' (to get the private value and make it useful to me).  So, I see a string of hex digits.. Passing that to the constructor of a X509Certificate2 throws an error with path too long... So what do I do with it to get it back into a X509Cert?

Comment: var sec2 = _keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(CertSecretPath)).Result;
                    X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sec2.Value));  Was attempted, but failed.   Not sure what to do with the 'value' I get back

Comment: The GetCertificateAsync() works to give me a cert, but doesn't have the obvious parameter to the request (includePrivateKey = false) to make it useful :-(

Comment: Azure-CLI version for this??

Comment: Downvote, there isn't much point in showing somebody how to store something without also demonstrating retrieval. Also the question was about C# and retrieval as an `x509Certificate2` object which the preceding comments show is not straightforward.

Comment: If people coming to this are as confused as I wa. it turns out you need to upload the .pfx to the `secrets` sections of Keyvault and not the `keys` section

Answer (score 9):

The original question asked how to retrieve the stored PFX as an `X509Certificate2` object. Using a Base64 process similar to that posted by Sumedh Barde above (which has the advantage of stripping the password), the following code will return a X509 object. In a real application, the `KeyVaultClient` should be cached if you're retrieving multiple secrets, and the individual secrets should also be cached.

```cs
public static async Task<X509Certificate2> GetSecretCertificateAsync(string secretName)
{
    string baseUri = @"https://xxxxxxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/";

    var provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var client =  new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(provider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
    var secretBundle = await client.GetSecretAsync($"{baseUri}{secretName}").ConfigureAwait(false);
    string pfx = secretBundle.Value;

    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pfx);
    var coll = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    coll.Import(bytes, "certificatePassword", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    return coll[0];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly right. Remember that you need to save your key under the `secrets` section of your keyvault and not the `keys` section of you keyvault

Comment: They really should have named the keys section something that better clarified it's meant for automated public key sharing and rotation, versus general purpose key storage...

Comment: Want to use this and similar solutions but with .Net Core 2.1, VS 2017 + Azure SDK getting: `'KeyVaultClient' does not contain a definition for 'GetSecretAsync'`.

Comment: @ttugates I'm not where I can check the code but I think it's in an extensions package that you either need to reference or maybe you just need a `using` statement.

Comment: @McGuireV10, found the extension package referenced at [Azure Key Vault configuration provider in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#package)

Comment: Actually the code was incorrect, I fixed it now. You should use the ```client``` object to do the async call.

Comment: In my case the certificate was in coll[2]. Please be sure to see your thumbprint in the correct array position*

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved this. First, convert your PFX file to a base64 string. You can do that with these two simple PowerShell commands:

```
$fileContentBytes = get-content 'certificate.pfx' -Encoding Byte
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes) | Out-File 'certificate_base64.txt'
```

Create a secret in Azure Key Vault via the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com). Copy the certificate base64 string that you created previously and paste it in the secret value field in your Azure Key Vault via the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com). Then simply call the Azure Key Vault from the code to get the base64 string value and convert that to a `X509Certificate2`:

```
private async Task<X509Certificate2> GetCertificateAsync()
{
    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
    var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://path/to/key/vault").ConfigureAwait(false);
    var pfxBase64 = secret.Value;
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pfxBase64);
    var coll = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    coll.Import(bytes, "certificatePassword", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    return coll[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the following answer, which describes how to do this using the latest .NET Azure SDK client libraries:

[How can I create an X509Certificate2 object from an Azure Key Vault KeyBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033073/how-can-i-create-an-x509certificate2-object-from-an-azure-key-vault-keybundle/64778106#64778106)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script for uploading pfx certificate in python using  azure cli

```
azure keyvault secret set --vault-name <Valut name> --secret-name <Secret Name> --value <Content of PFX file>
```

Getting the content of PFX file in python

```
fh = open(self.getPfxFilePath(), 'rb')
    try:
        ba = bytearray(fh.read())
        cert_base64_str = base64.b64encode(ba)
        password = self.getPassword()
        json_blob = {
            'data': cert_base64_str,
            'dataType': 'pfx',
            'password': password
        }
        blob_data= json.dumps(json_blob)
        content_bytes= bytearray(blob_data)
        content = base64.b64encode(content_bytes)
        return content
    finally:
        fh.close
    fh.close()
```

Comment: Downvote. Question was about retrieval as an `x509Certificate2` object using C#.