# Azure Key Vault Certificates does not have the Private Key when retrieved via IKeyVaultClient.GetCertificateAsync

Tags: c#, ssl, azure-keyvault, x509certificate2, kestrel-http-server

I have 2 approaches to do the same thing, but Azure has deprecated the one that works, and the other method doesn't work.

**The approach that works, but is deprecated:**

I store my PFX in Azure Key Vault **Secrets**. (when I create the secret I see a warning stating that this feature is deprecated)

and use the following code to retrieve it to create my certificate:

```
        SecretBundle secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(keyVaultUrl, "MyCert-Secret");
        X509Certificate2Collection exportedCertCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        exportedCertCollection.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value));
        X509Certificate2 certFromSecret = exportedCertCollection.Cast<X509Certificate2>().Single(s => s.HasPrivateKey);
```

credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40158825/1184584)

I'm able to use this certificate to host and access my application successfully.

**The approach that doesn't work, but I should be using:**

I store my certificate in the Azure Key vault **Certificates**

and use the following code to retrieve it and create the X509Certificate2:

```
        CertificateBundle certificateBundle = await keyVaultClient.GetCertificateAsync(keyVaultUrl, "MyCert-Certificate");
        X509Certificate2 certFromCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBundle.Cer);
```

The problem with this approach is that the certificate does not contain the private key. i.e. certFromCertificate.HasPrivateKey  is false.

**My Questions**

Why does certFromSecret have the PrivateKey, while certFromCertificate doesn't?

How can I retrieve a certificate from the key vault, where I can create a X509Certificate2 object to host my application in Kestrel with UseHttps.

Comment: @Adriano thank you. The 2nd half of your response helped resolve my issue. the Key point is how the AKV Certificate has 3 components - Key, Secret, & Certificate, and your break down of what exactly is stored in each of those. I'm posting the change I made to my code for others' reference.

Comment: Did you ever find a proper solution?

Comment: @Davy the posted answer is the approach i went with.

Comment: While suggested duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837362/keyvault-generated-certificate-with-exportable-private-key has good details on why it does not work it really does not show C# code to do so. It looks like this one actually talks about C# version - so re-tagged and voted to re-open.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The 2nd part of @Adrian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43839241/1184584) explains the concepts around the Azure KV Certificates very well, and I have changed my code as below to get the full certificate including the private keys:

```
        SecretBundle secret = await kv.GetSecretAsync(keyVaultUrl, certName);
        X509Certificate2 certificate = 
                 new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value));
```

The trick was to use `GetSecretAsync` instead of `GetCertificateAsync`. Please refer to Adrian's [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43839241/1184584) to see why the secret had to be used to get the full certificate with Private keys.

Note that you should use "Certificate identifier" property (url with "/secrets/") from Azure certificate's property page.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this answer here. The answer you refer contains only Power Shell code while this is in clean C#. Microsoft must really clarify in the documentation that GetCertificateAsync() method does not retrieve a useful certificate from vault.

Comment: I voted to re-open this question since the "duplicate" refers to PowerShell and this question is about C#. However since I can't post a new answer, I provided a fuller working method to retrieve all certs w/ private keys [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65093184/393931).

Comment: You might want to mention this article which contains tips for how to solve the exceptions you might get when you run the above code: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/11/19/loading-certificates-from-azure-key-vault-in-net-and-getting-it-working-in-azure-app-service/

Comment: This method thows error when retrieving private key.
"PrivateKey = 'x509Certificate.PrivateKey' threw an exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException'"

Answer (score 9):

The latest version of the SDK (Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates 4.2.0) now has the [DownloadCertificateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.certificates.certificateclient.downloadcertificateasync?view=azure-dotnet) method, which obtains the full cert (i.e. private key too) in a straightforward way.

The documentation states:

> Because Cer contains only the public key, this method attempts to
> download the managed secret that contains the full certificate.

`X509Certificate2 cert = await certificateClient.DownloadCertificateAsync(certName);`

Comment: What RBAC permissions does the managed identity need in order to be allowed to call that method? I can get it to work with "Key Vault Certificates Officer", but I am a bit sad to give my managed identity write-access to certificates. Do you know if I can get this to work with any level of read-only access? ("Reader" is not enough.)

Comment: this method throws asymmetric exception while retrieving private key.

Comment: Work perfect for me - version 4.5.0, thanks !