# Powershell, get a certificate from local store as a string, including the private key to store in KeyVault

Tags: powershell, certificate, x509certificate, azure-keyvault

Question: what do I need to do to get the Base64String of the entire certificate (including private key) in Powershell?

Case:
On Windows, I have a certificate on my User store.

In Powershell I do the following:

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Where-Object { $_.Subject -match "cert-subject" }
$certdata = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.RawData)
$str = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $certdata -AsPlainText -Force
```

Now in $str I find only the Public Key - the private key part is missing.

I am trying to upload $str as a secret in Azure KeyVault using:

```
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret `
    -VaultName $VaultName `
    -Name $SecretName `
    -SecretValue $certsecret `
    -ContentType 'application/x-pkcs12' `
    -Expires $cert.NotAfter `
    -NotBefore $cert.NotBefore
```

but the result is that this is a file that contains only the private key.

If I save the certificate manually from the local store and export the private key to a file, then use the Azure portal, I can upload the full cert pair.

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Answer partially from [How to serialize and deserialize a PFX certificate in Azure Key Vault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728213/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-pfx-certificate-in-azure-key-vault).

Provided that you have the Certificate and Private Key installed in your Local User certificate store and you need to authenticate to Azure with it, there are a number of steps involved.

```
$VaultName = 'myVaultName'
$SecretName = 'mySecretName'

$pfxFilePath = "C:\Path_to_\Exported_Key.pfx"
$pfx_password = "yourpassword"
# Password to be used for exported PKS12 file
$pfx_password_securestring = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "yourpassword" -Force -AsPlainText
# Export (exportable) private key to portable pfx
$cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Where-Object { $_.Subject -match "cert-subject" }
$cert | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath $pfxFilePath -Password $pfx_password_securestring

$flag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable
$collection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection 
$collection.Import($pfxFilePath, $pfx_password, $flag)
$pkcs12ContentType = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12
$clearBytes = $collection.Export($pkcs12ContentType)
$fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($clearBytes)
$certsecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $fileContentEncoded -AsPlainText –Force
$secretContentType = 'application/x-pkcs12'

Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret `
    -VaultName $VaultName `
    -Name $SecretName `
    -SecretValue $certsecret `
    -ContentType 'application/x-pkcs12' `
    -Expires $cert.NotAfter `
    -NotBefore $cert.NotBefore
```

Certificate Private key in CurrentUser certificate store needs to be exportable

Comment: Ok thanks - this tells me it is not possible to retrieve it as a string (byte array) - I knew I could do this via a file, but I wanted to avoid it not to leave the certificate on the file system - thx.