# How do I use the private key from a PFX certificate stored in Azure Key Vault in .NET Core 2?

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-2.0, x509certificate2, azure-keyvault

I've written an ASP.NET Core 2.0 website in C# and have Facebook authentication enabled, so it requires HTTPS.   I'm using the native Kestrel web server to host the site and have a listener set to take the PFX certificate per MS' documentation.  I can't seem to find a way for Kestrel to recognize the private key after recall from Key Vault.   I know it's present, as I wrote two debug statements that indicate it is, in fact present.

This is the function that I'm using to retrieve the secret, which is working.

```
        public static async Task<X509Certificate2> GetKeyVaultCert()
    {
        X509Certificate2 pfx;

        try
        {
            var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetToken));
            var secret = await kvClient
                .GetSecretAsync("https://macscampvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/letsencrypt").ConfigureAwait(false);

            byte[] bytes;
            if(secret.ContentType == "application/x-pkcs12")
                bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value);
            else
            {
                bytes = new byte[0];
                Console.WriteLine("secret is not PFX!!");
                throw new ArgumentException("This is not a PFX string!!");
            }
            var password = new SecureString();

            var coll = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            coll.Import(bytes, null, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            pfx = coll[0];
// File output added in case I end up needing to write cert to container
//          File.WriteAllBytes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "/Macs.pfx", bytes);
            Console.WriteLine(pfx.HasPrivateKey);
            Console.WriteLine(pfx.GetRSAPrivateKey());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"There was a problem during the key vault operation\n{ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }

        return pfx;
    }
```

The debug statements after the assignment call `pfx = coll[0];` tell me that this private key exists, but when I try to connect to the website using `lynx https://localhost` I receive the following exception:
`System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.`

So, how do I use the private key?   Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/digitaldelirium/b782938c9f15bf3ddbfef526d29a9f72) to the file in question.

I already was helped by [How to serialize and deserialize a PFX certificate in Azure Key Vault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728213/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-pfx-certificate-in-azure-key-vault?rq=1) but after following it, I got to this state.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that this is running in Ubuntu, so I don't have access to the Windows key stores.

Comment: If you have managed to load it, and HasPrivateKey is true, and GetRSAPrivateKey returned a non-null object, everything should work.  So the problem must be with how you're using it... so maybe some usage of what went wrong and the actual exception would help

Comment: The exception is too long to post, but I've added it to my gist, which also has implementation.
https://gist.github.com/digitaldelirium/b782938c9f15bf3ddbfef526d29a9f72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your gist you have the following code:

```
var keyVaultCert = GetKeyVaultCert().Result ??
    throw new ArgumentNullException("GetKeyVaultCert().Result");
pfx = new X509Certificate2(keyVaultCert.RawData);
```

The second line there removes the private key, because the `RawData` property just returns the DER encoded X.509 object.

`keyVaultCert` is already an `X509Certificate2` with a private key, you probably want to just use it.

```
pfx = GetKeyVaultCert().Result ?? throw etc;
```