# adding SSL automation task to pipeline

Tags: powershell, ssl, azure-devops, devops, pfx

I've created a power shell script that sets the SSL based on a provided PFX file.

Using the VSTS pipeline, what is the recommended way of passing PFX file to the script?

- Including PFX file in a solution
- getting the PFX file path on a target environment (contains dependency, 
  assuming that PFX file is already placed on target environment)

any other solution...?

Comment: It's just a file.  I'm assuming you're using `Import-PfxCertificate`

Comment: As long as the certificate is considered a sensitive data, you might want to keep it in the Azure Key Vault. Here is another similar SO thread about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728213/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-pfx-certificate-in-azure-key-vault. Also, quick googling brings a more solid article on the topic: http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/pfx-certificate-in-azure-key-vault/

Comment: thanks for responses.... but I am not using Azure

Comment: For the person who 'disliked' the question - based on my research I found 2 solutions. First - raises security concerns and second - adds dependency. Hence I am asking the community which of the specified options to be preferred or if there is any other solution. I hope you will think twice before before clicking on that button next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to pass authentication to the script is using option 1 (Including PFX file in a solution) as you listed.

After adding the pfx file into your solution, you can import certificates and private keys by `import-PfxCertificate`.

Detail usage and examples of Import-PfxCertificate, you can refer [this documen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-pfxcertificate?view=win10-ps)t.