# how to read certificate if web app is hosted over azure app service

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, certificate, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a asp.net core web api (app1) application which is calling another asp.net core web api (app2) and I am considering app1 as deamon app and I would like to follow client credentials with certificate rather than application secrets.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi#variation-daemon-application-using-client-credentials-with-certificates

Everything works fine till my both `app1` and `app2` running in local machine where I am reading the certificate like below,

```
private static X509Certificate2 ReadCertificate(string certificateName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(certificateName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("certificateName should not be empty. Please set the CertificateName setting in the appsettings.json", "certificateName");
        }
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;

        using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates;

            // Find unexpired certificates.
            X509Certificate2Collection currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);

            // From the collection of unexpired certificates, find the ones with the correct name.
            X509Certificate2Collection signingCert = currentCerts.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, certificateName, false);

            // Return the first certificate in the collection, has the right name and is current.
            cert = signingCert.OfType<X509Certificate2>().OrderByDescending(c => c.NotBefore).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return cert;
    }
```

The certificate is in local machine and I am reading it from here,

```
 using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
```

Now I want to host both app1 & 2 with azure app service, now question is how to read certificate?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728213/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-pfx-certificate-in-azure-key-vault ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deploying on an Azure compute (App service for example), there is no such thing as a `local` disk or certificate store available as such.

So, along with [the suggested changes](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/6-Deploy-to-Azure) to your application's configuration, you'd also need to do the following

1. Store your certificates in the [KeyVault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/services/key-vault/) (or equivalent) and fetch it from your code
2. Better, consider using [Managed Identities](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the certificate accessible. You can add the app setting: `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` with the value of `comma-separated certificate thumbprints` to be loaded.

Reference:
[Use a TLS/SSL certificate in your code in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5000570)